# Joining lists and accessing items fromt the joined list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, caml

I am working on a SharePoint Hosted app for SharePoint 2013 and I'm having real difficulty joining lists and accessing items from the joined list.  In my app I build a CAML query in which two lists are joined.  I then load the first list and execute the CAML against that list.  No errors at this point.  But when I try to access items from the joined list I get an error stating that the item I'm trying to access doesn't belong to the loaded list.  This is correct but it does belong to the joined list.

So my question.  How do I access items from the joined list?

Thanks

BTW, this is my CAML query in case it's relevant:

```
<View>
  <Joins>
      <Join Type='Inner' ListAlias='mTransactionHeaders'>
          <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='TransactionHeader' RefType='Id' />
              <FieldRef List='mTransactionHeaders' Name='ID' />
          </Eq>
      </Join>
  </Joins>
  <ProjectedFields>";
      <Field Name='mAdjustment' Type='Lookup' List='mTransactionHeaders' ShowField='Adjustment' />
  </ProjectedFields>
  <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='ItemStatus' />
      <FieldRef Name='ItemDate' />
      <FieldRef Name='mAdjustment' />
  </ViewFields>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but after struggling with adding fields from other lists in a view by help of projected fields and joins, I concluded that this is not working / bug, as per documentation it should.

The workaround we were thinking was to add additional lookup fields to the list showing the interesting columns from the foreign list. This should work fine as long as one doesn't need a column from a foreign list 2 degrees away, as one cannot display in a lookup column the value of a lookup column in the foreign list.